# Overlapping options of fonts after the font size and font series modification in memoir

Tags: fonts, memoir, fontsize, typewriter, cyrillic

I managed to set precise font size in `memoir` class on the basis of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373511/44348), e.g. `normalsize` is `14bp`.

After applying `tempora` package I have to reset `ttdefault`, e.g. by [Computer Modern Typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213835/44348).

As a result the `ttdefault` has lost `14bp` and become `13,77bp`.

How can I ask `14bp` come back?

MWE: `main.tex`

```
\providecommand*{\anyptfilebase}{bpfont} %set new fonts
\providecommand*{\anyptsize}{14}         %switch on bpfont14.clo - the copy of mem14.clo
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,*pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}[2014/03/24]% Языки: русский, английский

\usepackage{tempora} %TemporaLGCUni of Times type
%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lcmtt} %bigger
\begin{document}
    {\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames}

    {\normalsize\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames}

    {\itshape  \verb|ха-хаха Book_name_ch_AuthorsSurnames|}.

    {\normalsize\selectfont \verb|ха-хаха Book_name_ch_AuthorsSurnames|}

    {\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont\texttt{ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames}}

    {\texttt{\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames}}

    {\small{\texttt{ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames}}}
\end{document}
```

MWE: `bpfont14.clo` is `mem14.clo`([link](http://www.math.olympiaadid.ut.ee/latex/baltitee/bt2007/mem14.clo)) with 4 lines of the code replaced (please, set this file in the folder with `main.tex`):

```
\@setfontsize\normalsize{14bp}{18bp}    % SET 14 Adobe pt and 1,5 Adobe intervals. One can wish to delete all other text for precise result.
\abovedisplayskip 14\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus8\p@
\abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
\belowdisplayshortskip 7\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
```

PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really using `lmodern`, because it has no support for Cyrillic; what you get are the fonts defined in `t2alcmtt.fd` that are only defined at discrete steps. Indeed you get a warning about

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.82pt have occurred.
```

because this is the font definition:

```
\ProvidesFile{t2alcmtt.fd}
  [2001/08/11 v1.0a Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions]
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{lcmtt}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lcmtt}{m}{n}{%
  <13.82><16.59><19.907><23.89><28.66><34.4><41.28>%
  laltt8%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lcmtt}{m}{In}{%
  <13.82><16.59><19.907><23.89><28.66><34.4><41.28>%
  ilaltt8%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{lcmtt}{m}{it}{%
  <13.82><16.59><19.907><23.89><28.66><34.4><41.28>%
  lait1000%
}{}
\endinput
```

You have to redefine the font family.

```
\providecommand*{\anyptfilebase}{bpfont} %set new fonts
\providecommand*{\anyptsize}{14}         %switch on bpfont14.clo - the copy of mem14.clo
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,a4paper,*pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}[2014/03/24]% Языки: русский, английский

\usepackage{tempora} %TemporaLGCUni of Times type

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\EC@ttfamily}[5]{%
  \DeclareFontShape{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{
    <-8.5>#50800
    <8.5-9.5>#50900
    <9.5-10.5>#51000
    <10.5-11.5>#51095
    <11.5-13>#51200
    <13-15.5>#51440
    <15.5-18.5>#51728
    <18.5-22>#52074
    <22-27>#52488
    <27-32>#52986
    <32->#53583}{}}
\DeclareFontFamily{T2A}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{n}{latt}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sl}{last}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{it}{lait}
\EC@ttfamily{T2A}{cmtt}{m}{sc}{latc}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{n}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{cmtt}{bx}{it}%
  {<->ssub*cmtt/m/it}{}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\fn}{\expandafter\string\the\font}

{\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}

{\normalsize\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}

{\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont\texttt{ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}}

{\texttt{\fontsize{14bp}{18bp}\selectfont ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}}

{\small{\texttt{ха-хаха Book\_name\_ch\_AuthorsSurnames\fn}}}

14bp=\the\dimexpr14bp\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to use the `cmtt` fonts in the T1 encoding, similar code has to be added also for them.

Comment: thank you so much. It would be great if you explain, how to get the similar results for other fonts. Where can I read about `\EC@ttfamily`? What does `<-8.5>#50800....<32->#53583` mean? There is also no idea where could I find information about `\hyphenchar\font\m@ne` and `<->ssub*` to solve the problem by myself.

Comment: some explanations can be found on the following web-page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109673/44348

Comment: there is one extra problem I can not get global `\hyphenation` when I use `\texttt` in Index : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394500/44348